# How to pass a custom argument "--lang" to the "vite build" command?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, localization, vite, bundle

I am trying to build 6 different ReactJs bundles for 6 different languages.

As the first step I am trying to pass a custom `--lang` argument to the `vite build` command by adding the following 6 lines to the package.json of my project:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build en": "vite build --lang=en",
    "build de": "vite build --lang=de",
    "build fr": "vite build --lang=fr",
    "build nl": "vite build --lang=nl",
    "build pl": "vite build --lang=pl",
    "build ru": "vite build --lang=ru",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

Unfortunately, running any of the 6 new commands fails with:

```
> permanent-drawer@0.0.0 build de
> vite build --lang=de

file:///src/react-questions/permanent-drawer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:444
          throw new CACError(`Unknown option \`${name.length > 1 ? `--${name}` : `-${name}`}\``);
                ^

CACError: Unknown option `--lang`
    at Command.checkUnknownOptions (file:///src/react-questions/permanent-drawer/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:444:17)
```

Here a VS Code screenshot showing the error:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody please have a suggestion for me, how to make vite accept new `--lang` parameter?

My final target is to add a plugin which would take the lang parameter and use it to localize `__placeholder__` strings in the generated bundle file. So that at the end I can have 6 localized bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my problem by adding "--" before the custom argument:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build en": "vite build -- --lang=en",
    "build de": "vite build -- --lang=de",
    "build fr": "vite build -- --lang=fr",
    "build nl": "vite build -- --lang=nl",
    "build pl": "vite build -- --lang=pl",
    "build ru": "vite build -- --lang=ru",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

Also, at the end I didn't need this custom `--lang` parameter and have found a better way [to have localized bundles generated as the result of the "vite build" command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78039288/165071).